# PHP Sort by Specific Field in Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of the following structure:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [event] => event1 [Weight] => 2 )
```

And I am trying to sort by 'Weight'. I have tried this:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a['Weight'] > $b['Weight'] ){
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

But it isnt sorting by weight. It seems to be how i refer to weight but I am unsure how to do this correctly.

Comment: Where is the line which actually initiates the sorting? There must be something like `usort()`. Here is a correct example: https://eval.in/79635

Answer (score 1):

You can sort it like this:

```
uasort($array, function ($a, $b) {
    $c = $a['Weight'];
    $d = $b['Weight'];
    if ($c == $d){
        return 0;
    }
    else if($c > $d){
       return 1;
    }
    else{
       return -1;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// Obtain a list of columns
//$data = Your Array
foreach ($data as $key => $row) {
    $weight[$key]  = $row['Weight'];
}

// Sort the data with volume descending, edition ascending
// Add $data as the last parameter, to sort by the common key
array_multisort($weight, SORT_ASC, $data);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem must be the function you use to do the actual sorting, Here is a complete example of how to sort in ether ascending or descending order.

```
$array = array(
        array( 'event'=> 'something', 'Weight' => 2),
        array( 'event'=> 'something', 'Weight' => 1),
        array( 'event'=> 'something', 'Weight' => 10),
        array( 'event'=> 'something', 'Weight' => 10),
        array( 'event'=> 'something', 'Weight' => 0),
        array( 'event'=> 'something', 'Weight' => 1),
        array( 'event'=> 'something', 'Weight' => -10), 
    );

function weightCmp($isAscending = true) {
    return function($a, $b) use ($isAscending) {
        $diff = $a['Weight'] - $b['Weight'];
        return $isAscending ? $diff : $diff * -1;
    };
 }

usort($array, weightCmp());
var_dump($array);

usort($array, weightCmp(false));
var_dump($array);
```